# GAE Can not use cloudstorage on dev environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the dev build of GAE to upload some zip files, unzip and the edit them on the screen, as of now i'm just trying to see if the files can be opened after the upload and unzip.

If I try to open it any other place them on a background tasks i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ricardo/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/home/ricardo/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/home/ricardo/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/home/ricardo/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 292, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ricardo/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 314, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "/home/ricardo/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/request_handler.py", line 148, in __call__
    environ[http_runtime_constants.REQUEST_ID_ENVIRON])
KeyError: 'HTTP_X_APPENGINE_DEV_REQUEST_ID'
```

Here's the code:

```
class ExportConfiguration(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
def post(self, store_id):
    # upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
    bucket = '/' + BUCKET
    upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
    # write_retry_params = cloudstorage.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
    file = zipfile.ZipFile(upload.open())
    # logging.info(file)
    for name in file.namelist():
        outfile = file.read(name)
        outfile_list = name.split('/')
        for idx, path in enumerate(outfile_list):
            if path == 'bundles':
                node = outfile_list[idx - 1]
                outfile_path = 'data/{}/{}'.format(node, '/'.join(outfile_list[idx:]))
        params = {'path': '{}/{}'.format(bucket, outfile_path), 'file': outfile}

        task = Task(url='/tasks/write_loaders/',
                    params=params,
                    method='POST',
                    target='background-tasks')
        task.add()
        # outfile_full = '{}/{}'.format(bucket, outfile_path)
        # logging.info(outfile_full)
        # gcs_file = cloudstorage.open(outfile_full, 'w', options={'x-goog-meta-foo': 'foo', 'x-goog-meta-bar': 'bar'}, retry_params=write_retry_params)
        # gcs_file.write('outfile')
        # gcs_file.close()
    # file.extract()
    # file = str(self.request.POST.get(' filename'))
    # open(str(self.request.POST.get(' filename')).split('"')[1])
    # blob_info = upload_files[0]
    stats = cloudstorage.listbucket(bucket)
    for s in stats:
        logging.info(s.filename)
    logging.info(dir(stats))
    resp = {'code': 0, 'result': 'Success'}
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps(resp, separators=(',', ':')))


class LoaderWriter(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        path = self.request.POST.get('path')
        file = self.request.POST.get('file')
        file = file.encode('utf-8')
        file = etree.XML(file)
        gcs_file = cloudstorage.open(path, 'w')
        gcs_file.write(etree.tostring(file))
        gcs_file.close()
```

I tried to see if this was a gcs configuration problem, to no avail, has anyone else run into the same problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be related to the fact that you are extending `BlobstoreUploadHandler`. Apparently, this handler strips http headers like `HTTP_X_APPENGINE_DEV_REQUEST_ID` which are required for further API calls performed by `gcs` library.

If you try to open the file from a regular handler `webapp2.RequestHandler` it should work.

Comment: @Ricardo, has this answer been useful for you? Or maybe Dan's answer was? Either way, should you think that any of these answer is useful, please consider accepting it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Potential approach based on @Peuchele's answer.

In my case I was able to work around a similar problem caused by the differences between `blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler` and `webapp2.RequestHandler` by using double inheritance. Something like:

```
class ExportConfiguration(webapp2.RequestHandler,
                          blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
```

or (the inheritance order may matter):

```
class ExportConfiguration(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler,
                          webapp2.RequestHandler):
```

Note that this approach *might* not work in all cases, depending on the handler's implementation.